# How to intercept downloads of blob generated in client side of website through puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a page on this link (https://master.d3tei1upkyr9mb.amplifyapp.com/report) with 3 export buttons.
These export buttons generate XLSX, CSV, PDF on the frontend, and hence there are no URLs for XLSX, CSV, PDF.

I need puppeteer to be able to download or get or intercept the blobs or buffers of these files in my node backend.

I tried different ways to achieve this but still haven't figured out.

It was possible through playwright library through the code written below. But I need to be able to do it with Puppeteer.

```
const {chromium} = require('playwright');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext({acceptDownloads: true});
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/');

    const [ download ] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForEvent('download'), // <-- start waiting for the download
        page.click('button#expoXLSX') // <-- perform the action that directly or indirectly initiates it.
    ]);

    const path = await download.path();

    console.log(path);

    const newFile = await fs.readFileSync(path);

    console.log(newFile);

    fs.writeFile("test.xlsx", newFile,  "binary",function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    });

    await browser.close()
})();
```

Is there any way?

Comment: For context, in my case, the blob isn't actually generated until the user clicks the link (They're using react-csv). I cannot use a `fetch()` request, as the url/blob is empty, as no link has been clicked.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it only works for the xlsx but you see the general idea of what I did I hope ;-;

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to simulate the click on the frontend and allow `puppeteer` download the file to the location of your choice? You can easily download the file this way with the following:

Edit: You can determine when the file download completes by listening to the `Page.downloadProgress` event and checking for the `completed` state. Getting the actual filename saved to disk isn't 100% guaranteed with this method, but you are able to get what is termed the `suggestedFileName` from the `Page.downloadWillBegin` event, which in my tests thus far (at least on the example page in the question) does match the filename persisted to disk.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');
const downloadPath = path.resolve('./download');


(async ()=> {
  let fileName;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
      'https://master.d3tei1upkyr9mb.amplifyapp.com/report', 
      { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }
  );
  
  await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
      behavior: 'allow',
      downloadPath: downloadPath 
  });

  await page._client.on('Page.downloadWillBegin', ({ url, suggestedFilename }) => {
    console.log('download beginning,', url, suggestedFilename);
    fileName = suggestedFilename;
  });

  await page._client.on('Page.downloadProgress', ({ state }) => {
    if (state === 'completed') {
      console.log('download completed. File location: ', downloadPath + '/' + fileName);
    }
  });

  await page.click('button#expoPDF');
})();
```

Comment: How do I get the filename that was saved? How do I know when the file was downloaded?

Comment: You could do another waitForNavigation to be sure the file was downloaded before acting on it. And in this specific case, we know the filenames beforehand: CSV_EXPORT.csv, ExcelExport.xlsx, and repo.pdf. I've updated the code to include the navigation wait.

Comment: We don't always know the filenames before, as if it already exists, it will rename it to `(1)` or whatever. This seems like a clunky solution, not a huge fan of the `waitForNavigation` especially since there may be scripts on the page which cause no idle time.

Comment: Full disclosure, figuring this out took way longer than I expected! The upside is I learned a ton about the Chrome DevTools protocol. Anyway, I updated my code. We're able to know when the download completes by listening to the `Page.downloadProgress` event and checking for the 'completed' state. The filename isn't 100% foolproof, but we can get what's called the `suggestedFileName` (which in my tests have always been the actual filename) by listening to the `Page.downloadWillBegin` event.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Full disclosure, after a few days, this was my ended up solution (Was using puppeteersharp). https://i.imgur.com/rIrRVLH.png

Comment: lol yeh... unfortunately, you don't have as much control as you would with the `playwrite` library. there may be some way to use the `blob*` URL that is generated for the download to actually control writing the file to disk yourself if you wanted to go down that rabbit hole. You'd  end up with a duplicate download but at least you would have the control and 100% will know the filename.... overall though, I think what the solution above ultimately works.