# puppeteer: how to intercept blob request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

There was a answer about how to resolve blob download, the link as follow. [How to intercept downloads of blob generated in client side of website through puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450807/how-to-intercept-downloads-of-blob-generated-in-client-side-of-website-through-p)

But I want to intercept those requests which initator was script in browser. It seems that this request is blob type. The image as follows:

[image]

When following above example, the blob request did not intercept, so how do I intercept this request?

My code as follow:

```
import {Browser, connect, Page} from "puppeteer";
(async () => {
  const browser = await connect({
    browserURL: `http://127.0.0.1:4444`,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });

  const page = await this.browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on("request", async res => {
    // do somethings
  });
  page.on("response", async res => {
    // do somethings
  });

  const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await cdp.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
      behavior: 'allow',
      downloadPath: './'
  });
  // there is no download, it means that blob request don't intercept 
  await cdp.on('Page.downloadWillBegin', ({ url, suggestedFilename }) => {
    // do somethins;
    
  });
  // there is no download
  await cdp.on('Page.downloadProgress', ({ state }) => {
    if (state === 'completed') {
      // do somethins;
    }
  });
  const url = `https://amap.com`;
  await page.goto(url);
})()
```

Comment: Please share your code and the site as a [mcve]. Thanks.